# WCF Data Services Authentication

Tags: wcf-data-services

EDIT: I've decided to go for WCF Data Services as opposed to MVC3

Now that I have decided to go for WCF Data Services - I need a way to authenticate and authorise users.

Have looked at setting up a SQLMembership DB, but am struggling to actually authenticate the users.  My clients won't be .NET applications - most likely will be an iPhone/Android app that will call the RESTFul WCF Data Service to get data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Authentication**

WCF Data Services allow for a variety of authentication options, as described on MSDN : Securing WCF Data Services. From the available methods, Windows authentication is the most secure, using either the **NTLM**  or **Kerberos** mechanism. Due to the constraints on cross-platform availability, the most appropriate and secure authentication method that can be used is NTLM, as it is available on almost all current platforms: Android (from version 4.0 "*Ice Cream Sandwich*"), iOS, Linux, UNIX, Windows.

Setting up Windows authentication for an OData service hosted on IIS means disabling Anonymous Access and enabling Integrated Windows authentication. A more detailed guide can be found at [Odata and Windows Authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/05/10/odata-and-authentication-part-2-windows-authentication.aspx).

For a more fine-grained control of the users allowed to access the service, access can be granted or denied to both user roles/groups, as well as specific users, directly from the configuration file (i.e. web.config). The syntax for allowing access for a specific user is described below. For maximum security, it is advised to deny access to all users/groups, and then explicitly allow access, as required. The rules in between the authorization tags are taken in order (i.e. allowing user DOMAIN\user access takes precedence over the denial for all users)

```
   <authorization>   
      <allow users="DOMAIN\user"/>
      <-- Deny access to every other authenticated or anonymous user
      <deny users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
```

If the authorization tag is not explicitly defined in the configuration file, then IIS will authenticate and allow access for all connecting users that are recognized (in the Active Directory or local machine).

Setting up Windows authentication in a cross-domain environment is possible, but requires either:

- a trust to be established between the domains (so that IIS can authenticate external users), or
- the same username/password combination to be present on both domains
  or
- the client in the external domain authenticates with credentials
  valid for the server domain.

The available options for such situations are described in more detail in [this](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/05/crossing-domain-boundaries-windows-authentication/) blog post.

**Impersonation**

In order to be able to log in to the database, and retrieve the desired data using the Windows Account credentials sent to the WCF Data Service, the service needs to impersonate the user. This can be done in either in code, or in configuration

- In the configuration file (i.e. web.config), the following settings
  must be made:

> ```
>    identity impersonate="true"
> ```

- If it is not desired for the entire service to run under the
  credentials of the connecting user, impersonation can be set up
  programmatically, where needed, in the following way:

  > lUser = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, WindowsIdentity)
  >
  > lUserContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(lUser.Token)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm not looking for Windows Authentication as users will be stored using an  SQLMembership Database

Comment: thanks for the post , is it the same when trying to authenticate from ios ? I am working on a framework to call WCF service from ipad and iphone

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using ServiceStack.net with MVC 3.  ServiceStack is a Web Service framework that plays very well with MVC 3, includes a NuGet package to set everything up, and works natively with JSON.  The best thing about it is no configuration (as opposed to WCF) and the simple and powerful code-first approach.  It is also very fast.  See [servicestack.net](http://www.servicestack.net) for the download and my [tutorial](http://www.curlette.com/index.php?p=161) for getting started with it.  From my tutorial you can replace the Tridion code in the repository with your own DB code to store data.